# Test fails when separated into different files

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

At the moment I've got test suites for `Service` and `AnotherService` inside the same file i.e `service.test.js`.

When I run `npm test`, as is, tests for both `Service` and `AnotherService` run fine and pass.

But if I move the test suite for `AnotherService` to `anotherservice.test.js` the test from `service.test.js` fails, which is odd.

Anyone know why?

snippet from `package.json` ..

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js",
    "test": "mocha && jshint .",
```

code inside `service.test.js` ..

```
// this works fine
describe('Service', function() {
  describe('delete()', function() {
    it('should respond with a 401 as we are supplying user and no password', function(done) {
      request(app).delete('/item/0033cb8e-86a4-4dc1-9c2e-a07ca226d43f/')
        .set('x-header-db', 'db')
        .set('x-header-db-host', 'host')
        .set('x-header-db-credname', 'uname')
        .set('x-header-db-credpass', '')
        .expect(401)
        .end(done);
    });
  });
});

// this works here, but if moved to another file the test above fails
describe('AnotherService', function() {
  describe('delete()', function() {
    it('should respond with a 401 as we are supplying user and no password', function(done) {
      request(app).delete('/item/0033cb8e-86a4-4dc1-9c2e-a07ca226d43f/')
        .set('x-header-db', 'db')
        .set('x-header-db-host', 'host')
        .set('x-header-db-credname', 'uname')
        .set('x-header-db-credpass', '')
        .expect(401)
        .end(done);
    });
  });
});
```

snippet of directory listing

```
├── package.json
├── README.md
├── src
│   ├── serivce.js
│   └── anotherservice.js
└── test
    ├── service.test.js
    └── anotherservice.test.js
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how mocha is configured, but that type of behavior is usually a configuration problem.

Comment: I don't have a mocha config file, so using defaults

Comment: do you have an error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went with simply ..

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js",
    "test": "mocha ./service.test.js && mocha ./anotherservice.test.js && jshint .",
```

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your package.json file and run this :

```
"scripts": {
"start": "node app.js",
"test": "mocha && jshint ./*.test.js" //this will execute all the files with suffix test.js
```